# Python - 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, tuples

Hi i am stuck on change value in tuple type. i know i cant change value in tuple type but is there a way to change it ???

```py
a=[('z',1),('x',2),('r',4)]
for i in range(len(a)):
     a[i][1]=(a[i][1])/7  # i wanna do something like this !!!
```

i wanna change the the number in a to be the probability eg:1/7, 2/7, 4/7 
and is there a way to change the number of a to be a float ?? eg

```
a=[('z',0.143),('x',0.285),('r',0.571)]
```

Comment: If you want change a `tuple`, you really need a `list`.

Comment: Replace the entire tuple, not just a component. Bam!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change to `float` it's easy to just do

```
from __future__ import division # unnecessary on Py 3
```

One option:

```py
>>> a=[('z',1),('x',2),('r',4)]
>>> a = [list(t) for t in a]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
            a[i][1]=(a[i][1])/7


>>> a
[['z', 0.14285714285714285], ['x', 0.2857142857142857], ['r', 0.5714285714285714]]
```

Probably the best way:

```py
>>> a=[('z',1),('x',2),('r',4)]
>>> a[:] = [(x, y/7) for x, y in a]
>>> a
[('z', 0.14285714285714285), ('x', 0.2857142857142857), ('r', 0.5714285714285714)]
```

As requested in the comments, to 3 decimal places for *"storing and not printing"*

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 3
>>> [(x, decimal.Decimal(y) / 7) for x, y in a]
[('z', Decimal('0.143')), ('x', Decimal('0.286')), ('r', Decimal('0.571'))]
```

Comment: can the number somehow have 3 dp ??

Comment: for storing not for print it out

Comment: @TommyNgo `float`s [don't work like that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)... you can however use the `decimal` module, I'll update to show that. Also why do you only want 3 places **not** for printing?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is perhaps to turn the tuples into lists:

```
a=[['z',1], ['x',2], ['r',4]]
```

Unlike tuples, lists are mutable, so you'll be able to change individual elements.

Comment: @TommyNgo: `a = map(list, a)`.

Comment: @TommyNgo You have to make the items lists.  `a` is already a list.  Use `map` as seen above, or a list comprehension `new_list = [list(x) for x in a]`.